# Implement the min Priority_queue using vector<char, int>

Tags: vector, heap, priority-queue

I have to implement the  minimum `priority_queue` using `vector<char, int>`.
I am confused with the following code snippet.

```
priority_queue(int , vector<char, int> , greater<int> pq;
```

But this is absolutely wrong.

Comment: Did you posted the right code because at least a closing paranthese is missing? Please give more details where do you need help.

Comment: I want to make min heap in which 1st arg. of vector denote the key and 2nd weight .

Answer (score 0):

This should work :

```
priority_queue<int,vector< pair<char, int> >, greater< pair<char,int> > > PQ;
```

Comment: What do you mean by that you have not inserted any thing in the priority queue there, you are only inserting things in the vector.